# How to fix "kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventFail"

Tags: ios, swift, brightcove

I try to play video with Brigthcove.

First I try to play video with IMA ads.
About 10 videos are very well.
Then after that I found some issue.

I got failed sessions.

```
kBCOVIMALifecycleEventAdsLoaderFailed
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventPause
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventPlay
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventPlay
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventPlayRequest
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventPlayRequest
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventFail
kBCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEventPause
```

When I got this error I can't play any video after that.
First video is well ago when after got error can't play also.

Thank.